# Rails sms, email and voice messaging framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sms, twilio

Is there a framework built in rails that lets me do something like send a message and then based off of user preferences automatically determine whether a text message, voice message or email message should be sent (or any combination of the 3 options)?

Also, if there is a framework like this, does it have support for receiving text messages or email messages and taking actions?

I know this is a big ask. The reason I am asking is because I have started implementing a system like this and am considering making it open source but I am curious if there is anything  out there like this already that I should learn from first before publishing my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A full blown framework? No.

A helper library that does 95.2% of what you're looking for? Yes.

Using the Twilio gem - https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby - you can send SMS or Voice with a handful of lines of code. You don't need to know their mobile carrier either, you can just send the SMS/Call for pennies per message/minute.

If you need a hand with it, I'm happy to help. You can reach me at keith @ twilio.com.